# Skip deployment steps during automatic octopus deployment from TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I want to skip certain steps on a Octopus project while doing automated deployment from Teamcity. I have read through the [docs](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/integration/teamcity) on how to set this up, and got it to do the deployment.

How do I go about skipping some Octopus deployment steps while using this ? Or should I create a seperate octopus project for automated deployments that only contain the basic steps, then another project containing all the steps  ?

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What steps in particular do you want to skip?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this (or something similar) with a fake environment.

We have an environment called "live - inactive" which only contains the octopus server machine. This step queries our load balancer and promotes the deployment to one of our real live environments. Our deployment process steps are not configured to run in this fake environment. So the iis config etc is skipped

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following documentation http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Deploying+releases

`--skip=step name`  as part of 
**Additional command line arguments** for OctopusDeploy: Create release Step in Teamcity